# Failed to launch chrome using puppeteer in Centos 7

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, chromium, google-chrome-headless

I have read every thread in stackoverflow, github and blogs before posting this issue.

I am trying to run `puppeteer` in Centos 7

Here's my simple program

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless:true,
    args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"]
})
const page = await browser.newPage()
await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 800 })
await page.goto('https://www.nytimes.com/')
await page.screenshot({ path: 'nytimes.png', fullPage: true })
await browser.close()
```

```
Error: Failed to launch chrome!


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

    at onClose (/home/admin/web/xxxx/puppet_test/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:348:14)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (/home/admin/web/xxxx/puppet_test/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:337:50)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at Interface.close (readline.js:416:8)
    at Socket.onend (readline.js:194:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1241:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

I have installed all dependencies required and suggested in google blog and [Puppeteer documentation](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#chrome-headless-doesnt-launch-on-unix)

I even tried installing google-chrome additionally and giving puppeteer its path
`executablePath: '/usr/bin/google-chrome'` but it didn't help.
`ldd chrome | grep not` was of no use either.

Puppeteer runs very well in my other Centos7 installations but don't understand why it isn't working here. Please HELP!

```
Node v12.20.1
Puppeteer v2.0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Those dependencies you installed relate to Chromium, not Chrome. Then you mention `/usr/bin/google-chrome`, so perhaps you're using google Chrome and not Chromium. They are not identical products.

Try installing and running Chromium:

```
# yum install chromium
```

Comment: I tried both Google Chrome and Chromium Browser, nothing seems to work

Comment: Does Chromium run on your system when you launch it for normal browsing?

Comment: When I run `google-chrome --version` or `chromium-browser --version` I get
`Segmentation fault`

Comment: `segfault at fffffffc01e34341 ip 00007fc397987dff sp 00007fffed113da0 error 5 in chromium-browser[7fc3977d7000+9ad8000]`

at /var/log/messages